# What will stand in for the JMM Employment Center this year?

Tags: soft-question, career, conferences, mathjobs

The Joint Mathematics Meetings will be virtual this year, and there is no indication of there being an Employment Center (virtual or otherwise). What is the story with the [Employment Center](https://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/employment-center/employment-center)? Will it be delayed or held at MathFest or some such thing?

This has to do with research only tangentially...particularly if we can get people jobs so they can do the research!

Comment: I think that the AMS and MAA are still sorting out a lot of JMM details, including things like the employment center. I wrote to ask them to add an item to their FAQ with whatever they know now.

Comment: Thanks @Joe Silverman. Hopefully some inkling will be found soon in the FAQ...

Answer (score 2):

My university hired during the fall of 2020 and we did Zoom interviews instead of the Employment Center at the JMM. That seems to have become standard, to get down to the short-list of candidates who you bring to campus. We did the same in the fall of 2022. [I just wrote an answer about this at Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202083/about-interviews-for-teaching-positions-in-math-during-jmm/208920#208920), with a bit of the evolution of how we do our 20-minute interviews (plus what I've seen at other universities) and how nowadays Zoom is more common than JMM.